# Window does not appear

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I wrote a program that creates an icon in the system tray and clicking the right mouse button displays the context menu of the 3 points Notes, Create new note and Quit, by pressing the menu Create new note form should appear, but it does not appear. Why?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
import sys

class NoteForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        uic.loadUi("note.ui", self)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    tray = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon()
    icon = app.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DesktopIcon)
    tray.setIcon(icon)
    tray.show()
    CreateMenu(tray, app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

def CreateMenu(tray, app):
    m1 = QtGui.QMenu("Menu 1")
    m2 = QtGui.QMenu("Notes", m1)
    actNewNote=QtGui.QAction("Create new note", m1)
    actNewNote.triggered.connect(viewNote)
    #m1.addAction("Create new note", viewNote)
    m1.addMenu(m2)
    m1.addSeparator()
    m1.addAction("Quit", app.quit)
    tray.setContextMenu(m1)

def viewNote():
    note=NoteForm()
    note.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

note.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>WindowNote</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="WindowNote">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>707</width>
    <height>356</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Заметка</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>671</width>
     <height>331</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="TitleNote"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QTextEdit" name="textNote"/>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="buttonOK">
      <property name="text">
       <string>OK</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="buttonCancel">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Отмена</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="buttonDeleteNote">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Удалить заметку</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `viewNote` function doesn't save a reference to the instance of `NoteForm` it creates. The `show()` function returns immediately without blocking, and so the dialog gets garbage-collected straight after it's shown.

To fix it, use [exec_](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec) to run the dialog, or keep a global reference:

```
def viewNote():
    note = NoteForm()
    note.exec_()
```

or:

```
def viewNote():
    global note
    note = NoteForm()
    note.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `QDialog.exec_()` in the `viewNote()`. And also enable the `Create new Note` action. So like this:

```
def CreateMenu(tray, app):
    m1 = QtGui.QMenu("Menu 1")
    m2 = QtGui.QMenu("Notes", m1)
    actNewNote=QtGui.QAction("Create new note", m1)
    actNewNote.triggered.connect(viewNote)
    m1.addAction("Create new note", viewNote)
    m1.addMenu(m2)
    m1.addSeparator()
    m1.addAction("Quit", app.quit)
    tray.setContextMenu(m1)

def viewNote():
    note=NoteForm()
    note.show()
    note.exec_()
```

Or you can pass `note` as a global, so like this:

```
def viewNote():
    global note
    note = NoteForm()
    note.show()
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. The OP has already started the main event loop in `main()`, and this is needed in order for the menu signal handling to work. The `NoteForm` class is a QDialog, which has its own event loop.

Comment: Why don't you steal the rest of my answer, and get rid of the redundant `note.show()` line before `note.exec_()` as well?

Comment: I didnt "Steal" your answer I went back and fixed it based on this site, http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qdialog.html#exec